# Nested Components Scaffolding

Tags: jss

I'm currently setting up a new JSS project using the JSS React boilerplate and I ran into an issue regarding the scaffolding of components. When using the scaffolding script I can use `jss scaffold Foo` to scaffold a Foo component in the `src/components` folder as well as the needed sitecore files.

I'm trying to achieve scaffolding nested components in the `src/components` folder a React.js front-end SPA. With the current way of scaffolding, I'm not able to do this. Placing the scaffolded component in a subfolder in `src/components/Bar/Foo` won't work. Even when I keep the same folder structure in `sitecore/definitions/components`. I suspect this is due to some paths being used while scaffolding in seperate files.

Is there a way to have nested components in `src/components` to build a structured project?

Answer (score 3):

Assuming you used one of the sample apps to bootstrap your app, the scaffolding script is located in `scripts/scaffold-component.js` and is fully customizable to suit your needs and patterns. In this same file you can customize the manifest definition scaffolding as well.

You'll likely also want to change the component factory generation script `scripts/generate-component-factory.js` as well (if you're using it) to match the nested structure of your components.